ESP32 with CH343 serial timeouts on flash but monitor works
I'm trying to flash an ESP32 over a CH343 USB to UART device using an M2 Mac running Sonoma. When I connect over USB the device enumerates, I am able to open a serial monitor, and I can even check the value of the fuses. Attempting to flash the device fails immediately however, with a 01070000: Operation timed out error. I've also attempted a to manually flash with esptool and --trace enabled, but just see the following output repeating:
TRACE +0.000 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.103 No serial data received.


The problem here turned out to be the built-in CH343 driver in OS X Sonoma. I installed the driver here and it resolved the issue: https://github.com/WCHSoftGroup/ch34xser_macos
